# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'createComponent' of undefined .ngAfterViewInit dynamic loader

Tags: angular

I am trying to load a component dynamically into another child component a toaster.  So toaster being a component will load another component in its content area.

Tried as per this article: https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-how-to-get-viewcontainerref-before-viewchild-query-is-evaluated-f649e51315fb

Without the directive. If it worked then I was going to try the directives.

```
<ng-template #regularContent>
    <div class="sn-content" [innerHTML]="content"></div>  
    <div #target></div>              
</ng-template>

@ViewChild('target', {read: ViewContainerRef}) vc: ViewContainerRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(TestComponetComponent);
  this.vc.createComponent(factory);
}
```

Comment: I suppose that's because you may read the element inside the template that hasn't been rendered

Comment: Correct! Thank you.